# How to write dispatcher sevlet configuration in java based config class (WebAppInitializer)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

i am learning java and spring, can someone please help me how can i write the below given dispatcher servlet configuration in java based config class (WebAppInializer), tried hard to achieve but could not succeed. thanx in advance.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/admin.htm" view-name="admin"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/services.htm" view-name="services"/>

<!--
Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
define an explicit mapping for it.
-->

 <!--
 The index controller.
  -->
 <bean name="indexController"
 class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
 p:viewName="home"/>
 </beans>
```

**My Initializer.java**

```
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;


@Order(1)
public class Initializer extends
AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
return new Class[] {DatabaseConfig.class };
 }
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
return new Class<?>[] { WebAppConfig.class };
 }

 @Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.myproject")
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
     registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/admin.htm").setViewName("admin");
    registry.addViewController("/services.htm").setViewName("services");
  }

@Bean(name = "indexController")
  public ParameterizableViewController indexController(){
    ParameterizableViewController parameterizableViewController = new ParameterizableViewController();
    parameterizableViewController.setViewName("home");
    return parameterizableViewController;
  }

}
```

Comment: this is giving HTTP Status 404 - /project/

Comment: Nikhil do i need to change something in inializer.java also?

Comment: Nikhil thanx for helping me with useful info, now its perfectly working.